# wpf border and TextBlock color gap

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a border and a text block inside with the same background color, and there is a hairline gap in between them showing parent background which is white. How to get rid of it

```
<Border Background="Red" CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="Red">
 <TextBlock Background="Red"></TextBlock>
</Border>
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm not seeing the gap at all, can you post a screen shot?

Comment: I copied your code and am not seeing a gap.  Do you have any other styles applied anywhere?

Comment: I can repro this using slightly different xaml. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43300615/119738 (This question should probably be closed as dupe once that other one gets an accepted answer)